# IntegrityError at /answer/ NOT NULL constraint failed: answer_answer.post_id

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have 2 models one for **Question** and one for **Answer** when i submitted **answer** form its throws me an error like this: **IntegrityError at /answer/
NOT NULL constraint failed: answer_answer.post_id** I'm trying to fix it by adding **blank=False** and **null=False** and deleted my migrations but still the error is there. How can I solve this problem please.

I want a user to be able to post an answer to a single question the error comes from my **My_Answer** view and it's highlight this line of code:

```
return super (My_Answer,self).form_valid(form)
```

my models

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    body = RichTextField(blank=False, null=False) 
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = RichTextField(blank=False, null=False)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

the views

```
def viewQuestion(request, pk):
    question = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
    answers = Answer.objects.filter(post_id=question)
    context = {'question':question, 'answers':answers}
    return render(request, 'viewQuestion.html', context)


class My_Question(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
     model = Question
     fields = ['title', 'body', 'category']
     template_name = 'question.html'
     success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super (My_Question, self).form_valid(form)

class My_Answer(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Answer
    fields = ['answer']
    template_name = 'answer.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super (My_Answer, self).form_valid(form)
```

the viewQuestion template:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <h1>{{question.title}}</h1>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <br>
    <h3 style="font-family: arial;">{{question.body|safe}}</h3>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <h5>{{question.user.username.upper}}</h5>
</div>
<!--question-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <a href="{% url 'answer' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Post Your Answer</a>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<!--answer-->
<div class="container">
    {% for answer in answers reversed %}
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <p>{{answer.user}}</p>
        <p>{{answer.answer|safe}}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you are not assigning post to a an answer while creating an answer thats why its throwing an error post_id integrity error.

Comment: No, Look at my ViewQuestion view. You can see a variable **answers = Answer.objects.filter(post_id=Question)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving an answer instance with only answer from form and user from request user but where is a post id which cannot be none and is required.

you url patterns should look like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('question/<int:pk>/', viewQuestion, name='view-question'),
    path('question/<int:pk>/answer/', My_Answer.as_view(), name='answer'),
]
```

You only have to change url in viewQuestion.html as

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <a href="{% url 'answer' pk=question.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">Post Your Answer</a>
</div>
```

And in answer views as

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
    return super (My_Answer, self).form_valid(form)
```

So basically you are saving answer instance without post pk, I passed post pk in url params and get in answer post view to save in form instance. This should work now!

Comment: How can I do this please ? Can you edit your answer please

Comment: do you have post id in url params?

Comment: No,  **<a href="{% url 'answer' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Post Your Answer</a>**

Comment: This is my url I did not include an id into it.

Comment: No its say **kwargs is not defined** then i added it in to my: **def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):** the error is gone but it also throws an error like this sir: **KeyError at /question/1/answer/
'pk'** so i added pk like this **def form_valid(self, form, pk, **kwargs):** its also throws an error like that: **My_Answer.form_valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'**

Comment: how can I solve this problem sir ?

Comment: just do as I mentioned. I have tested code and it was working fine. Have yo changed url link in the viewQuestion.html?